# Trying to create something like command line game in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std, header-files

The code is giving me these errors

```
Severity Code   Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error    C2664  'int printf(const char *const ,...)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'void' to '...'    game    C:\Dev\game\game\game\player.h  20  
Error    C2664  'Player::Player(char *,int *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'char *'    game    C:\Dev\game\game\game\main.cpp  8
```

I have been trying to fix my code for hours but I figured out what I should do to fix it.

entity.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Entity {
public:
    int* hp;
    char* m_Name = nullptr;
    virtual char* GetName() { return m_Name; }
    virtual void Death(std::string message) {
        if (*hp <= 0) {
            std::cout << message << std::endl;
            *hp = 100;
        }
        else if (hp == nullptr)
            *hp = 100;
    }
};
```

player.h

```cpp
#pragma once 

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "entity.h"


class Player : public Entity {
public:
    char* m_Name;
    int* hp;
    Player(char* name, int* health)
        : m_Name(name), hp(health) {}; // m_name = name is the same
    char* GetName() override { return m_Name; }
    ~Player() { std::cout << "Why did you destroy me!" << std::endl; }
    int* getHealth() { return hp; }
    void Death() {
        if (*hp <= 0) {
            printf("%c was killed\n", *m_Name);
            *hp = 100;
        }
        else if (hp == nullptr)
            *hp = 100;
    }
};
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "player.h"

int main() 
{
    Player* pp = new Player(135, "%");
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `health` using a `int* ` pointer?  That should be simply `Player(char* name, int health)` and `int hp;` as class member. Also you switched order of these constructor parameter. After you changed what I formerly said, it should be `new Player("%", 135);`

Comment: `else if (hp == nullptr)
            *hp = 100;` This definitely won't work at runtime.

Comment: I'd recommend you work through your textbooks chapter covering pointers again There are so many errors in your code, that it's hard to fix everything here for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with your code.

- As has pointed out in @AriaN's answer, you mixed up the order of arguments in the `Player` constructor.
- You really should avoid these unnecessary pointers. In particular, you dereference `hp` in `if (*hp <= 0)`. You check agains nullptr will never be carried out.
- You should check `if (hp != nullptr)`  then you can safely dereference it, currently its undefined behavior as you only dereference it when it is a nullptr.
- You should consider adding a virtual destructor to you base class.
- Why is `Entity::Death(...)` virtual? `Player::Death()` has a different signature and does not override it.
- You already have defined `hp` and `m_Name` in the base class.
- You are leaking memory, as you never delete `pp` in main.

Here is an example with the suggested changes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Entity {
public:
    int hp;
    std::string m_Name;
    Entity(const std::string &name, const int health) 
        : m_Name(name), hp(health){}
    virtual ~Entity() = default;
    virtual const std::string &GetName() const { return m_Name; }
    virtual void Death(const std::string &message="") {
        if (hp <= 0) {
            std::cout << message << std::endl;
            hp = 100;
        }
    }
};

class Player : public Entity {
public:
    Player(const std::string &name, const int health)
        : Entity(name, health) {}; // m_name = name is the same
    const std::string &GetName() const override { return m_Name; }
    ~Player() { std::cout << "Why did you destroy me!" << std::endl; }
    int getHealth() const { return hp; }
    void Death(const std::string &message="") override {
        if (hp <= 0) {
            std::cout << m_Name << " was killed.\n";
            std::cout << message;
            hp = 100;
        }
    }
};

int main() 
{
    int health = 135;
    Player* pp = new Player("Player", health);
    pp->hp = -1;
    pp->Death();
    delete pp;
}
```

Comment: I started learning C++ a few days ago. I'm sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @PavlosEfstathiou You didn't wast my time. Keep learning!

Answer (score 1):

The Player class first argument is `char*` and second is `int*` so:

```
int health = 100;
Player* pp = new Player("Alex", &health);
```

Comment: I still get this error: ``` Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0289 no instance of constructor "Player::Player" matches the argument list game C:\Dev\game\game\game\main.cpp 7 
```

Comment: @PavlosEfstathiou because `"Alex"`  is a string literal which is const, therefore you need to declare `Player(const char* name, int* health)`. But this will lead to other errors. Basically you need to replace all `char *` with `const char *`. With these changes your code should compile, but there may be problems at runtime, I didn't check.

Comment: I compiled your code and it doesn't give me any error, and it runs fine! Your error is about wrong argument that you entered for Player instance, so double check that your arguments are fine

Comment: why you declare `m_Name` and `hp` in Player class too! You have them on Entity class so you don't need to declare them again! and your Player class constructor should be something like
`Player(char* name, int* health){
        m_Name = name;
        hp = health;
  }`